# jQuery-AJAX: How to disable a button on table row only when a condition is met

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to disable a button only when a certain condition is met. The buttons are generated dynamically and they have a dynamic ID as well. These buttons are on a table and they appear on each row. (2 buttons per row and one of those two should always be disabled).

The way I've done it so far, it disables all of the (same) buttons on all rows if the condition is met and I only need to disable the ones meeting the condition.

This is the code I have so far.

```
<script>
/*
Search
*/
$('document').ready(function()
{
        $('#submit-btn').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#fld_name').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#fld_id').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#fld_current').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#fld_new').prop('disabled', true);

    /* disable search button until ID length is reached */
    $('#search-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#search_value').keyup(function()
    {
        var id_search = $('#search_value').val().length;
        if(id_search < 6){
        $('#search-btn').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else if (id_search == 6){
        $('#search-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });

    $("#search-btn").on('click', function(){

            var data = $("#search-form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'search.php',
            data : data,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#msg-block").fadeOut();
                $("#search-btn").html('<img src="../base_images/btn-loader-1.gif" /> &nbsp; Searching...');
                $('#search-btn').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#user_list tbody').empty();
            },
            success :  function(response)
               {    result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

                    if(result.search_result == "found"){
                        $("#search-btn").html('Search');
                        $('#fld_name').prop('disabled', false).prop('readonly', true);
                        $('#fld_id').prop('disabled', false).prop('readonly', true);
                        $('#fld_current').prop('disabled', false).prop('readonly', true);
                        $('#fld_new').prop('disabled', false);
                        $("#fld_id").val(result.fld_id);
                        $("#fld_name").val(result.name);
                        $("#fld_current").val(result.current_status);
                                //load table with search results.
                                $.ajax({
                                type : 'POST',
                                url  : 'test.php',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data : data,
                                cache: false,
                                success :  function(result)
                                   {
                                   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#user_list').offset().top }, 2000);
                                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                                        $('#user_list tbody').append(
                                            '<tr id="user_tb_row">'
                                            +'<td class="center tb_rec_id" id="'+result[i].tb_rec_id+'">' + result[i].tb_rec_id + '</td>'
                                            +'<td class="center tb_uni_id" id="'+ result[i].tb_emp_id +'">' + result[i].tb_emp_id + '</td>'
                                            +'<td>' + result[i].tb_name + '</td>'
                                            +'<td class="center tb_status_id" id="'+result[i].tb_status+'"><span class="label label-sm label-success center">' + result[i].tb_status + '</span></td>'
                                            +'<td class="center">' + result[i].tb_date + '</td>'
                                            +'<td>'
                                            +'<div class="margin-bottom-0">'
                                            +'<button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline margin-bottom access_activate" id="act_'+result[i].tb_rec_id+'">'
                                            +'<i class="fa fa-search"></i> Activate </button>'
                                            +'<button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline margin-bottom access_suspend" id="sus_'+result[i].tb_rec_id+'">'
                                            +'<i class="fa fa-search"></i> Suspend </button>'
                                            +'</div>'
                                            +'</td>'
                                            +'</tr>');

                                            //This is what I have been testing.
                                           if($('.tb_status_id').attr('id') == 1){
                                            $('#act_'+result[i].tb_rec_id).prop('disabled', true);
                                            $('#sus_'+result[i].tb_rec_id).prop('disabled', false);
                                            }
                                            else if($('.tb_status_id').attr('id') == 0){
                                            $('#act_'+result[i].tb_rec_id).prop('disabled', false);
                                            $('#sus_'+result[i].tb_rec_id).prop('disabled', true);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        }
                                });

                            }
                    else if(result.search_result == "not_found"){
                            //do stuff
                    }
                    else {
                            //do other stuff
                    }
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You dont show how this script gets activated!!!!!!

Comment: But assuming you are using click, then you know which button is `this` and therefore you can find the other button in the same table row

Comment: The script is very very long but I will scrape out some functions that have nothing to do with this and I will update my question in a minute.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've added more details. Hope it helps to better understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to accomplish what I needed. the if statement wasn't going to work because it will take every element with the same class and disable or enable it if the condition was met. Also, if/else cannot be used as is inside append.

In order to make it work, I added used a **ternary condition** within the appended elements which will generate the content of each row individually based on that particular condition. (in this case the buttons).

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    $('#user_list tbody').append(
        '<tr id="user_tb_row">'
        +'<td class="center tb_rec_id" id="'+result[i].tb_rec_id+'">' + result[i].tb_rec_id + '</td>'
        +'<td class="center tb_uni_id" id="'+ result[i].tb_emp_id +'">' + result[i].tb_emp_id + '</td>'
        +'<td>' + result[i].tb_name + '</td>'
        +'<td class="center tb_status_id" id="'+result[i].tb_status+'"><span class="label label-sm label-success center">' + result[i].tb_status + '</span></td>'
        +'<td class="center">' + result[i].tb_date + '</td>'
        +'<td>'
        +'<div class="margin-bottom-0">'
        +(result[i].tb_status == 1 ? //this is the conditional statement.
        '<button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline margin-bottom access_activate" id="act_'+result[i].tb_rec_id+'" disabled>' //disabled button where condition is met
        +'<i class="fa fa-search"></i> Activate </button>'
        +'<button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline margin-bottom access_suspend" id="sus_'+result[i].tb_rec_id+'">'
        +'<i class="fa fa-search"></i> Suspend </button>'
        : //else statement
        '<button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline margin-bottom access_activate" id="act_'+result[i].tb_rec_id+'" disabled>'
        +'<i class="fa fa-search"></i> Activate </button>'
        +'<button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline margin-bottom access_suspend" id="sus_'+result[i].tb_rec_id+'">'  //disabled button where condition is met
        +'<i class="fa fa-search"></i> Suspend </button>'
        )
        +'</div>'
        +'</td>'
        +'</tr>');
}
```

I'm use that there are other ways to do this but this is the only way I figured out how to do it. Hope it helps others that might be looking to accomplish the same thing.